# Mosek runs indefinitely on large MIQCQP

Tags: optimization, cvxpy, mosek

We have a large-scale MIQCQP problem. Problem size:

```
Decision vars: ~9K (with 3K continuous and 6K integral vars)
Objective: 1 Linear expression
Constraints (linear): 35K linear constraints (9K lower bound + 9K upper bound + remaining inequality constraints)
Constraints (Quadratic): 1 quad constraint (with Q matrix size as 3K*3K, which is PSD)
```

When we use Mosek (via Cvxpy), it runs indefinitely (in the branch & bound logic). Moreover, from the mosek logs: `BEST_INT_OBJ` and `REL_GAP(%)` are displayed `NA` throughout.

Since this problem contains proprietary data, its difficult to share it.

Are there any general tips or tricks to speed up the problem?

(Weirdly, Gurobi can solve the same problem in less then a minute)

Comment: Can we get sub-optimal solution by changing the tolerance level?

Comment: Different solvers use different techniques to tackle your problems, so if you found a good solution with Gurobi, why do you want to replicate this performance with another solver?

Comment: If BEST_INT_OBJ is NA then it has not found any integer solution yet so changing tolerances probably won't help much. You could try to increase the parameters responsible for heuristics. The best way really is to write to Mosek support.

Comment: Thanks Michal! Would setting a Initial guess help the MIQCQP optimizer?

Comment: @pqrz That very often helps but the starting point has to be feasible. However there is no way to pass an initial point to Mosek in cvxpy.

Comment: No problem, then we'll switch to its pyomo interface

Comment: But Is there something like [mosek supports initialization for only Simplex optimizer (meaning only LP problem type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67430604/initialization-of-decision-variables-value-in-mosek-solver-via-cvxpy-framework#:~:text=warmstart,interface) ?